# Setting value with Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I have this code:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

/***********************************************
* Drop Down Date select script- by JavaScriptKit.com
* This notice MUST stay intact for use
* Visit JavaScript Kit at http://www.javascriptkit.com/ for this script and more
***********************************************/

var monthtext=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

function populatedropdown(dayfield, monthfield, yearfield){
     var today=new Date()
     var dayfield=document.getElementById(dayfield)
     var monthfield=document.getElementById(monthfield)
     var yearfield=document.getElementById(yearfield)
     for (var i=0; i<31; i++)
         dayfield.options[i]=new Option(i, i+1)
     dayfield.options[today.getDate()]=new Option(today.getDate(), today.getDate(), true, true) //select today's day
     for (var m=0; m<12; m++)
         monthfield.options[m]=new Option(monthtext[m], monthtext[m])
     monthfield.options[today.getMonth()]=new Option(monthtext[today.getMonth()], monthtext[today.getMonth()], true, true) //select today's month
     var thisyear=1920;  // fixed start year of 1900
     var nowyear = 1994;
     var diff = nowyear - thisyear +1; // number of years from 1900
     for (var y=0; y<diff; y++){
         yearfield.options[y]=new Option(thisyear, thisyear)
         thisyear+=1
     }
}
</script>

<script>
function getcombined(){
    var year = document.getElementbyId("yeardropdown").value;
    var month = document.getElementById("monthdropdown").value;
    var day = document.getElementById("daydropdown").value;
    var combineddob = year + "-" + "month" + "-" + day;
    document.getElementById("hidden1").value=combineddob
}
</script>


</head>

<body>
<form action="" name="someform">
<select id="daydropdown" name='day' value="daydropdown">
</select> 
<select id="monthdropdown" name='month' value="monthdropdown">
</select> 
<select id="yeardropdown" name='year'  value="yeardropdown">
</select> 
<input type='hidden' id='hidden1' name='dob' value="" />
<input type='submit' />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload=function(){
    populatedropdown("daydropdown", "monthdropdown", "yeardropdown")
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

I need the `<input type='hidden' id='hidden1' name='dob' value='' />` to update to `var combineddob` when the form is submitted.

I have tried several methods, but I do not know much about javascript so I am not good with these kinds of fixes.

I may be over looking something, but I have not yet figured out what is wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your html

```
<input type='submit' />
```

to this

```
<input type='submit' id="submitButton" />
```

and in your script

```
window.onload = function(){
    populatedropdown("daydropdown", "monthdropdown", "yeardropdown");
    var submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitButton");
    submitBtn.onsubmit = function(){getcombined();};
};
```

This will allow you to run the function in `onsubmit` when the submit button is clicked. It will in turn call the function `getcombined();` and then submit the form.

**EDIT**

Perhaps you should change these two lines:

```
var combineddob = year + "-" + "month" + "-" + day;
document.getElementById("hidden1").value=combineddob
```

to

```
var combineddob = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
document.getElementById("hidden1").value=combineddob;
```

and

```
var year = document.getElementbyId("yeardropdown").value;
```

to (note that `getElementbyId` is not a function)

```
var year = document.getElementById("yeardropdown").value;
```

Comment: Unfortunately that seems to not be working, is there an error in my getcombined function possibly..

Comment: There is a typo: getElementbyId but should be getElementById in your getcombined function.

change this line 
var year = document.getElementbyId("yeardropdown").value;

to 

var year = document.getElementById("yeardropdown").value;

Comment: it is not changing the value, in the url it just says dob= leaving it null

Answer (score 2):

If you want something to happen before a user submits the form, you should set the [onsubmit](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_form_onsubmit.asp) property of the form. In this case:

```
<script>
<!--
function getcombined(){
    var year = document.getElementById("yeardropdown").value;
    var month = document.getElementById("monthdropdown").value;
    var day = document.getElementById("daydropdown").value;
    var combineddob = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
    document.getElementById("hidden1").value=combineddob;
    return true;
}
-->
</script>


</head>

<body>
<form action="" name="someform" onsubmit='return getcombined();'>
```

I've added "return true" to the function to indicate that the form should actually submit afterwards. Also I fixed two typos, namely a lower case b in getElementbyId and a missing semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

First of all:

```
var year = document.getElementbyId("yeardropdown").value;
```

to:

```
var year = document.getElementById("yeardropdown").value;
```

Add onclick in submit button:

```
<input type='submit' onclick="getcombined();alert(hidden1.value);" />
```

Comment: The listener should be on the form's submit handler, not the button (see stewbasic's answer).

Comment: You are right @RobG,actually I want to show how to setting value in a button